# Detecting change in dynamically generated radio buttons with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to detect changes in dynamically generated radio buttons. I have a form that generates radio buttons and they're named according to their ID saved in the database. So it's something like

```
<input type="radio" name="data[Setting][47]" id="Setting47Entry" value="entry">
<input type="radio" name="data[Setting][47]" id="Setting47Standard" value="standard">

<input type="radio" name="data[Setting][48]" id="Setting48Entry" value="entry">
<input type="radio" name="data[Setting][48]" id="Setting48Standard" value="standard">

<input type="radio" name="data[Setting][49]" id="Setting49Entry" value="entry">
<input type="radio" name="data[Setting][49]" id="Setting49Standard" value="standard">
```

There is not pre-defined number of radio buttons that will appear. There could be 2 or even 20, it all depends on other options that the user has set.

I know how to detect changes if the names were static, but since the names are different for each user I don't know how to handle that.

Comment: if names are dynamic then use something static like classname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a `attribute starts with selector` try,

```
$('input[name^="data[Setting]"]').change(function(){  });
```

Comment: Thanks, it's detecting changes. I'm able to retrieve the newly selected value with $(this).val(), but how can I retrieve the name or id? I need to know not only the value, but the input itself.

Comment: you can access name/id etc.. using `$(this)` inside of that handler. can you tell me exactly what do you need.? may be an example.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I used $(this).attr('name')

Comment: @user1443519 you can simply use $(this).attr('name') to know that.!